# Modelos en Laravel

Tags: laravel

A ver, tengo una gran duda con esto de los modelos en Laravel. Resulta ser que en los modelos generalmente uno almacena todo el acceso a datos mediante métodos y consultas que se hace a la BD. Aquí no tengo eso bien claro, pues veo que el acceso a los datos mediante el ORM es mucho más fácil. Entonces me pregunto, ¿para qué los utilizo si desde un controlador puedo hacer las cosas? GRACIAS de antemano.

Comment: Los modelos son la representación en singular de cada tabla de la base de datod, por otro lado invocas a los modelos en cada controlador donde gracias al ORM y a sus métodos haces consultas a las tablas que estos representan

Comment: Lo que me quieres decir es que, gracias al ORM ya no tengo que hacer métodos en los modelos. ISmplemente se fucionan en el controlador a través de las buenas prestaciones que tiene el ORM???

Comment: Si en un primer paso eso que dices es válido

Comment: A ver, llevo tiempo programando en CodeIgniter y no estoy acostumbrado a esta manera de programar, simplemente estoy queriendo entender, por eso necesito aclarar algunas dudas como estas. Gracias @shadow pero hasta que punto esto es así,??? simpre estará lo correspondiente a la BD en el controlador???

Comment: No siempre pues he visto trabajos de algunos programadores donde gracias a la arquitectura de Laravel lo extienden y crean n capas con más funcionalidades

Answer (score 3):

Como en todo lenguaje/framework hay muchas maneras de realizar las cosas.

- ¿Con Laravel puedes hacer consultas directamente a la base de datos desde tus controladores? Sí. Mediante los [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/queries).
- ¿Puedes hacerlo de otro modo? claro, mediante el uso de [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent), su ORM, el cual es una implementación del patrón Active Record.
- ¿Entonces cuál es mejor? pues la respuesta de siempre: depende del caso de uso.

Si piensas realizar una aplicación pequeña, con solo unas cuantas clases/tablas pues puedes utilizar Query Builders. Haciendo esto estarías rompiendo el patrón MVC pues estás ingresando lógica del modelo en el controlador, que en realidad solo debería mapear las cosas.

Por otro lado, haciendo uso de modelos, te permite desacoplar tu lógica:

- Tu modelo es el único encargado de gestionar las operaciones de los objetos/instancias de esa clase.
- Centralizas el mantenimiento en una sola clase.

Imagina el siguiente caso. Tienes una tabla `colaboradores` en la que existe el campo `con_hijos` que te devuelve un boolean indicanto `true`/`false`. Pero por necesidades del negocio, este campo debe cambiarse a un tipo `int` el cual debe indicar el número de hijos del colaborador.

Si depositas toda la lógica en tus controladores, deberías de ir a todos los métodos de los controladores en los que hayas hecho uso de este atributo y modificar la lógica para saber si es padre o no (en caso no hayas creado un helper).

Pasarías de esto:

```php
public function miFuncion()
{
    // colaborador X
    $colaborador = DB::table('colaboradores')->where('id', 1)->first();

    // si cumple la condición actual
    if ($colaborador->con_hijos) // <----------------
    {
        // se ejecuta alguna acción
        $this->notificarBonoPaternidad($colaborador);
    }
    else
    {
        // se ejecuta otra acción
    }
}
```

a esto:

```php
public function miFuncion()
{
    // colaborador X
    $colaborador = DB::table('colaboradores')->where('id', 1)->first();

    // ajustando para que cumpla la condición
    if (count($colaborador->con_hijos)) > 0)  // <----------------
    {
        // se ejecuta alguna acción
        $this->notificarBonoPaternidad($colaborador);
    }
    else
    {
        // se ejecuta otra acción
    }
}
```

En cambio, si depositas esta lógica en tu modelo le das la responsabilidad de gestionar estos cambios pues solo te interesa el valor retornado e añadir la lógica para saber el número de hijos. Por lo que la actualización de este modelo se replicaría en todas las partes de tu programa donde se haga uso de esa función:

**app/Colaborador.php**

```php
// saber si es padre/madre
public function getConHijosAttribute()
{
    return $this->con_hijos > 0; // retorna un boolean
}

// devolver el número de hijos
public function getCantidadHijosAttribute()
{
    return $this->con_hijos;
}
```

Por lo que en tu controlador no necesitas actualizar nada:

```php
public function miFuncion()
{
    // colaborador X
    $colaborador = Colaborador::find(1);

    // si cumple la condición actuar
    if ($colaborador->con_hijos)
    {
        // se ejecuta alguna acción
        $this->notificarBonoPaternidad($colaborador);
    }
    else
    {
        // se ejecuta otra acción
    }
}
```

---

Y esto es solo un caso de uso, en realidad los modelo son muy útiles pues te permite [crear atributo](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor)s en base a otros o alguna lógica en particular (como hice arriba), darle un formato específico antes de devolverlos a los controladores/vistas ([casting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting)). Además de [definir tus relaciones](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships) y, con ellos, [limitar el alcance](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#query-scopes) de estas a través de condiciones especiales. En fin, son muchas cosas que te permite hacer este hermoso framework.

---

Hay muchas maneras en las cuales puedes optimizar tu código y desacoplar la lógica para que este puede ser mantenible en el tiempo. Laravel lo hace realmente fácil. Te recomiendo que leas la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs), está super explicada y no aburre para nada y también que veas las series de [Laracasts](http://laracasts.com).

Comment: Excelente explicacion! felicitaciones